# How can I align text to bar plots with position_fill in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I thought I understood aligning text to plots but this one has me stumped. I want to use `position_fill()` to show the percentage shares of groups, but include the group counts with `geom_text` to indicate that different groups have different numbers of observations. Because some groups have very small shares, I decided to just have the labels be fixed at either end of the plot.

Here is my first attempt, using an example group variable `long_sepal` from `iris` that is just whether or not the `Sepal.Length` is bigger than 5.5.

I make a custom `y_label` variable that is either 0 or 1 to map to the `y` aesthetic of `geom_text`, so that the labels are always at the extremes of the plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = Sepal.Length > 5.5) %>%
  count(Species, long_sepal) %>%
  mutate(y_label = if_else(long_sepal, 0, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = n, fill = long_sepal), position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(label = n, y = y_label, group = long_sepal),
    hjust = 0,
    position = position_fill()
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

All well and good, but the `FALSE` labels are hanging off the edge of the plot. No problem, I'll just change the values of `y_label`:

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = Sepal.Length > 5.5) %>%
  count(Species, long_sepal) %>%
  mutate(y_label = if_else(long_sepal, 0, 0.5)) %>% # This has changed
  ggplot(aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = n, fill = long_sepal), position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(label = n, y = y_label, group = long_sepal),
    hjust = 0,
    position = position_fill()
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And nothing has changed. Interestingly, it seems to work, sort of, on changing the first value in `if_else` but not the second, as below. The left labels will move but don't seem to align with 0.25 as I would expect. Any ideas why? Is my mental model of how geoms work breaking here? I suspect it is something to do with `position_fill` but I am not sure.

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = Sepal.Length > 5.5) %>%
  count(Species, long_sepal) %>%
  mutate(y_label = if_else(long_sepal, 0.25, 1)) %>% # Now the text moves, but not where I expect
  ggplot(aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = n, fill = long_sepal), position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(label = n, y = y_label, group = long_sepal),
    hjust = 0,
    position = position_fill()
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Using `hjust = "inward"` does move the labels just inside the plot, but still doesn't explain why my changing of `y_label` doesn't move them. I can't put them in the middle of the plot still, for example, or even offset from the plot edge a bit.

Comment: Your `geom_text` is just using the data of `y_label` to determine the `position_fill`. This means that whatever your value for `y_label` is, it will be "filled out" to sit between 0 and 1. So for values `0.25` and `1`, it will be a stacked total of 1.25 remapped to fit between 0 and 1. If you want to manually place the values at a certain point of the x-axis, don't use `position_fill` for your `geom_text`.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. That also means I guess that I basically can't move the right number with `position_fill`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the comments, especially from [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188915/how-can-i-align-text-to-bar-plots-with-position-fill-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1#comment97116360_55188915), I realised that I can use `position_identity()` to get the desired result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  mutate(long_sepal = Sepal.Length > 5.5) %>%
  count(Species, long_sepal) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(y_label = if_else(long_sepal, 0.01, 0.99)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = n, fill = long_sepal), position = position_fill()) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(label = n, y = y_label, group = long_sepal),
    hjust = "inward",
    position = position_identity()
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, and note that `position_identity` is the default for `geom_text`.

Comment: Ah I should have realised! I'm used to replacing it in the more common bar plots where I have `position_dodge` and you need it to dodge the text, but here it's counterproductive.

Comment: `position_fill` in `geom_text` can be useful, e.g. `ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = n, fill = long_sepal)) +
    geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
    geom_text(
        mapping = aes(label = n),
        position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)
    )`. Just not for this exact example.