# How to align geom_text() in a facetted and flipped stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, stacked-bar-chart

Here is my fake data:

```
dat1 <- structure(list(A_B = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), percentage = c(49.2629769158808, 
50.7370230841193, 64.4899165250794, 35.5100834749206, 59.3111128788481, 
40.6888871211519, 85.3899516501997, 14.6100483498003, 80.5933773112794, 
19.4066226887206, 84.3750256827502, 15.6249743172498, 62.8269574848769, 
37.1730425151231, 69.5582018265724, 30.4417981734276, 56.5840999142665, 
43.4159000857335, 100, 0, 67.4302746354917, 32.5697253645083, 
27.3784794349813, 72.6215205650187, 58.0885854897603, 41.9114145102397, 
100, 0, 89.005829015544, 10.994170984456, 57.1694599627561, 42.8305400372439, 
100, 0, 54.2251244585246, 45.7748755414754, 74.4838466287125, 
25.5161533712875, 74.6413724456935, 25.3586275543065), facet = c("Facet 1", 
"Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", 
"Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", 
"Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", 
"Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 2", 
"Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", 
"Facet 1", "Facet 2", "Facet 2", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1", 
"Facet 1", "Facet 1", "Facet 1"), id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the chart:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat1, aes(id, percentage, fill = factor(A_B))) + 
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("coral", "lightblue"),
                    breaks=c('A', 'B'))+
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ facet, scale= "free")+
  geom_text(data = subset(dat1, percentage != 0), aes(label = sprintf("%.1f%%", percentage), group = A_B), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5), size = 5)
```

I get this:
[image]

When attempting to vertically align text within a single line for both `A` and `B` by adjusting the vjust argument in `position_fill()`, I encounter difficulties achieving a uniform alignment. Using `vjust=1` brings me closest to the desired outcome; however, this results in the text exceeding the boundaries. Using any other number in `vjust` results in a skewed formation of the percent numbers.

Comment: With the y-scales different in both facets, I'm not sure I understand what you're going for. If the y scales are different, then the bars will be different, then the alignment will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to position the values in B (blue one) at the beginning of each blue bar and the number in A (coral one) at the end. I am not sure if this is possible? the nearest approach I found here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188915/how-can-i-align-text-to-bar-plots-with-position-fill-in-ggplot2> but I can't transform it to my example.

Comment: Ah, I you're talking about a flipped `vjust`, so actually an apparent `hjust`? So that the labels are close to the blue/red break in the bar? That makes more sense now. I'm not at my computer now to try, but maybe something like `vjust = ifelse(A_B == "A", .95, .05)` (or I might have gotten those flipped). Pretty sure you can put `vjust` inside `aes()` for `geom_text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `vjust` parameter you can only position both labels at the bottom, top or center. Instead, for what you are trying to achieve I think you are better off using `position="idenity"` and setting the `y` position and the horizontal alignment using an `ifelse`. Also note that I switched to `geom_label` to add some padding (I'm not a big fan of using `h/vjust` for this task (: ).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat1, aes(id, percentage, fill = factor(A_B))) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("coral", "lightblue"),
    breaks = c("A", "B")
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ facet, scale = "free") +
  geom_label(
    data = subset(dat1, percentage != 0),
    aes(
      y = ifelse(A_B == "A", 1, 0),
      hjust = ifelse(A_B == "A", 1, 0),
      label = sprintf("%.1f%%", percentage)
    ), size = 3, fill = NA, label.size = 0
  )
```

[image]